# Register software app as hardware joypad?

Tags: c#, hardware, emulation

I know I'm stepping into something complicated here, but it's better I get help now before I mess things up.

I'm looking into writing an application to act as a joypad on a touch screen tablet (running Windows 7, written in C# .Net). Previously I thought about it just emulating keyboard input, but I want to take it up a level, directly emulating a physical, hardware game pad. Where do I begin doing this?

Comment: Vague hint: You need to write a driver.  This will not be straightforward.

Comment: Not completely sure you can even write device drivers or virtual drivers in .NET and C#, look at the Windows DDK documentation.

Comment: Damn... I was hoping to avoid drivers in hopes of hijacking a DLL or two from XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a device driver for this.

A hardware joypad is one type of human input device (HID). Fortunately, the UMDF (user-mode driver framework) is a library that supports HID devices (except keyboards and mice). UMDF exposes a COM-like API, so in theory it should be possible to write one in C#.

However, consider the following quote by Doron Holan on 2008-10-06:

> i do not think any one has really tried
>   a HID UMDF filter before, so you will be blazing new ground

I'm not aware of any sample UMDF HID driver, but [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/888_umdf_4_you/archive/2010/05/28/10017056.aspx) may be a good starting point.

In all honesty, as much as I dislike hijaking and injection, it would probably be easier than a driver.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm even capable of using XNA or some other framework to output controller states, that would be the easiest way